# Enable button if any EditText field has text but disable if all are empty

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have 4 EditText input fields and a button. I want the button to be enable if any of these fields has text in it but disable if all of them have no text entered. The closest solution I came up with is to use the combineLatest but that only works if ALL the fields have text in them:

```
fun observeTextInputs(inputs: MutableList<Observable<String>>) {
        for (i in inputs) {
            mIputFieldsObservables.add(i)
        }

        disposables.add(
            Observable.combineLatest(mIputFieldsObservables) { args ->
                args.map { it ->
                    it.toString()
                }
            }.subscribe { array ->
                for (item in array) {
                    Log.d("LinkedIn Text Input", item)
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

I think it's possible to still use this with some modification. If not, what other solution do I have?

Comment: This library might help https://github.com/whalemare/RxValidator2

Answer (score 0):

You can create `TextChangeListener` for your `edittexts` and disable the button if they are empty:

```
  youredittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    //put your code here.ex: if s.length==0 do something

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int aft )                                                                          
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {


    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for an RxJava solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this library: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding by Jake Wharton, in order to deal with views via RxJava 2

[EditText example with RxBinding (variable **it** is EditText here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5F5f.png)